# Find Law of X of random variable

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve this task i.e.  the probability space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mathbb{P})$, where

$\mathbb{P}=0.1 \delta_{-2}+0.7 \delta_{1}+0.2 \delta_{2}$

If $X(\omega)=\omega^{2}$, then $\mathbb{P}_{X}([0,4))$ is:

I think solutions is as folows:
$\mathbb{P}_{X}=0.3 \delta_{4}+0.7 \delta_{1}$

$\mathbb{P}_{X}([0,4)])=0$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\mathbb P_X([0,4))&=\mathbb P\{\omega \mid \omega ^2\in [0,4)\}\\
&=\mathbb P((-2,2))\\
&=\mathbb P((-2,1))+\mathbb P(\{1\})+\mathbb P((1,2))\\
&=\mathbb P\{1\}=...
\end{align*}

Comment: ok thank you I guess answer is 0.3

Comment: @EdwardMoor: No ! And to guess is never a good idea ;-)

Comment: Hmm according to you answer would be 1(some of three probabilities) , but I  don't think this is the right answer or am I missing something

Comment: @EdwardMoor: Yes it's one ! Why don't you think that it's the right answer ? Does $0.1+0.2+0.7=1$ ? If you are not sure, then it's a problem...

Comment: 4 is not part of  interval see  how interval is defined i.e [0,4)

Comment: @EdwardMoor: You are completely right. Sorry for the mistake. I edited my answer.